# How to declare a dictionary compatible with any type in C#

Tags: c#, oop, dictionary, ado.net

I have created an abstract base class which is the parent of all other classes. I have another class for database connection where I a m fetching records and I wanted those records to be converted into the objects of class which I will pass to function. I have written function like ..

```
enter code here

//Class AppConnection.cs

public static Dictionary<int, BaseClass> FetchObjects( string sqlQuery, BaseClass obj ) {

    DataTable dt = MyConnection.FetchRecords( sqlQuery );

    Dictionary<int,BaseClass> objDict = new Dictionary<int, BaseClass>();

    for(int i=0; i < dt.Rows.count; i++ ) {
        obj.MapObjectByDataRow(dt.Rows[i]);      //Abstract function in BaseClass
        objDict.Add(obj.Id, obj);
    }

    return objDict;
}
```

I am calling this in child classes like this,

```
enter code here

class Customer:BaseClass 
{
    public static Dictionary<int, Customer> FetchCustomers() {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";

        Dictionary<int, Customer> dict = AppConnection.FetchObjects(sql, new Customer() );
        return dict;
    }

}
```

This gives error cannot convert implicitly

```
enter code here

Dictionary<int,BaseClass> to Dictionary<int,Customer>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here.  Does your code work?  If not, where does it fail?  Are you looking for a cleaner way of doing this or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a generic method?

```
public static Dictionary<int,T> FetchObjects<T>(string sqlQuery, T obj) where T : BaseClass
{
    DataTable dt = MyConnection.FetchRecords( sqlQuery );

    Dictionary<int,T> objDict = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    for(int i=0; i < dt.Rows.count; i++ ) {
        obj.MapObjectByDataRow(dt.Rows[i]);      //Abstract function in BaseClass
        objDict.Add(obj.Id, obj);
    }

    return objDict;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `public static Dictionary<int, T> FetchObjects<T>(string sqlQuery, T obj)...`